# How to iterate over dynamically updated elements with Selenium

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium

I want to load all documents from messages on mail site. Unfortunately I could not provide the link for this site because there is sensitive information, but I will try to describe the idea.

I use C# with Selenium and I believe site's frontend implemented with AngularJS because there is data-ng-click attribute. Unfortunately I never worked with AngularJS and don't really know how to approach.

Here is the structure of messages page:

[image: screenshot showing messages]

When I click on message there is a new page with required information. What I tried to do is to load all messages by clicking "Show more" button several times. The problem is if I open specific message page and return back all previously loaded messages are disappear and I should load them again. Is it possible to save the state of page with list of messages and iterate over each message? Or is there another approaches? Is there any chance I could get all notification values and call for each openDetails as in data-ng-click="openDetails(notification)"?

What I've tried to: create duplicate of message's list page in another tab. It doesn't work because duplicated page drops loaded messages and show first 10 messages.

Open page for specific message in another tab. I couldn't manage this because there no "open in new tab" entry in context menu.

Code for "Show more" button:

```html
<a type="button" class="button-second button-white button-small button-long-phone" data-ng-click="nextPage()">Show more</a>
```

Code for list of messages:

```html
<div data-ng-include="feedsListTpl"><!-- ngRepeat: notification in notifications -->
<div data-ng-class="{
        'notification-item': true,
        'feed-im': notification.data.imOrgName,
        'feed-GEPS': notification.feedType,
        'notification-item_unread': notification.unread,
        'notification-item_unread-thread': notification.feedType === 'GEPS' &amp;&amp; notification.data &amp;&amp; notification.data.unreadThread &amp;&amp; notification.data.unreadThread > 1
    }" data-ng-repeat="notification in notifications" class="notification-item feed-GEPS notification-item_unread">
    <div class="grid-wrap__row">
        <a data-ng-click="openDetails(notification)" class="grid-wrap__col-lg-1 grid-wrap__col-md-1 grid-wrap__col-sm-1 grid-wrap__col-md-land-1 pad-top-24 pad-bottom-24">
            <div class="visually-hidden">Author</div>
            <div class="status-inbox"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="grid-wrap__col-lg-12 grid-wrap__col-md-9 grid-wrap__col-sm-5 grid-wrap__col-md-land-13 pad-top-x-sm pad-bottom-x-sm sm-pad-bottom-none">

            <div>
                <div class="grid-wrap__row">
                    <a data-ng-click="openDetails(notification)" class="grid-wrap__col-lg-24 grid-wrap__col-sm-6 grid-wrap__col-md-12">
                        <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType!== 'FEEDBACK' --><div data-ng-if="notification.feedType!== 'FEEDBACK'" class="offset-top-min">
                            <!-- ngIf: notification.hasLegal ||  notification.isLegal || notification.data.hasRegLetter --><span data-ng-if="notification.hasLegal ||  notification.isLegal || notification.data.hasRegLetter" class="red-flag"></span><!-- end ngIf: notification.hasLegal ||  notification.isLegal || notification.data.hasRegLetter -->
                            <span data-ng-class="{'plain-text-bold': (notification.unread &amp;&amp; notification.feedType != 'DRAFT') || (notification.feedType === 'GEPS' &amp;&amp; notification.data &amp;&amp; notification.data.unreadThread &amp;&amp; notification.data.unreadThread > 1), 'plain-text': !notification.unread || notification.feedType == 'DRAFT'}" class="plain-text-bold">
                                <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType !== 'CLAIM' && notification.feedType !== 'RETURN' --><span data-ng-if="notification.feedType !== 'CLAIM' &amp;&amp; notification.feedType !== 'RETURN'" data-ng-bind-html="(notification.status === 'outbox' &amp;&amp; notification.data.deptMessageType &amp;&amp; notification.data.deptMessageType === 'ORDER' ? notification.data.toName || notification.title : notification.title) | highlight:filter.query">Author</span><!-- end ngIf: notification.feedType !== 'CLAIM' && notification.feedType !== 'RETURN' -->
                                <span data-ng-bind-html="notification.subTitle | highlight:filter.query">Theme</span>
                                <span class="notification-item__unread-thread">&nbsp;(1)</span>
                            </span>
                            <!-- ngIf: ($root.userType === 'B' || $root.userType === 'L') && ((notification.data.orderCreator && notification.data.orderCreator.formattedLoginName) || (fullView && notification.data.orderDescription)) -->
                            <!-- ngIf: !fullView && !notification.data.imOrgName -->
                            <!-- ngIf: showRemoveDraftSign(notification) && $root.isLk -->
                        </div><!-- end ngIf: notification.feedType!== 'FEEDBACK' -->

                        <!-- ngRepeat: snippet in notification.data.snippets -->
                        <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType === 'FEEDBACK' -->
                    </a>
                    <!-- ngRepeat: textSnippet in notification.data.snippets -->

                    <!-- ngIf: notification.data.imOrgName && !fullView -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a data-ng-click="openDetails(notification)" class="grid-wrap__col-lg-4 grid-wrap__col-md-2 grid-wrap__col-sm-6 grid-wrap__col-offset-sm-1 pad-top-x-sm sm-pad-top-extra-sm pad-bottom-x-sm align-right sm-align-left offset-top-min">
            <div class="grid-wrap__row notification-item__controls">
                <div class="grid-wrap__col-lg-4 grid-wrap__col-md-12 grid-wrap__col-sm-6">
                    <div data-ng-show="!notification.deleteError &amp;&amp; isUnread(notification)" class="notification-item__new">updated</div><div data-ng-show="iconsObj.setFixedIcon(notification)" class="notification-item__fixed offset-left-extra-sm ng-hide"></div><!-- ngIf: showNotificationDate(notification) --><div data-ng-class="{'small-light-text': !isUnread(notification), 'notification-item__date': isUnread(notification)}" data-ng-if="showNotificationDate(notification)" class="nowrap small-light-text inline-block offset-left-extra-sm notification-item__event-date notification-item__date"><!-- ngIf: notification.data.snippets[0].type === 'IM' --><!-- ngIf: notification.data.snippets[0].type !== 'IM' --><span data-ng-if="notification.data.snippets[0].type !== 'IM'">Вчера 19:19</span><!-- end ngIf: notification.data.snippets[0].type !== 'IM' --></div><!-- end ngIf: showNotificationDate(notification) -->
                </div>
                <div class="grid-wrap__col-lg-4 grid-wrap__col-md-12 grid-wrap__col-sm-6">
                    <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType == 'DRAFT' && !notification.deleteError && !notification.data.reminder -->
                    <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType == 'GEPS' && notification.status == 'draft' -->
                    <!-- ngIf: notification.hasQuiz -->
                    <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType == 'ORDER' && notification.data &&  notification.data.gisDoSsExtId && notification.data.gisDoLink && !notification.hasQuiz -->
                    <!-- ngIf: !notification.deleteError && notification.feedType == 'PAYMENT' && notification.data.amount -->
                    <div data-ng-show="notification.deleteError" class="notification-item__error ng-hide">
                        do not deleted
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<!--  end ngRepeat: notification in notifications -->

<div data-ng-class="{
        'notification-item': true,
        'feed-im': notification.data.imOrgName,
        'feed-GEPS': notification.feedType,
        'notification-item_unread': notification.unread,
        'notification-item_unread-thread': notification.feedType === 'GEPS' &amp;&amp; notification.data &amp;&amp; notification.data.unreadThread &amp;&amp; notification.data.unreadThread > 1
    }" data-ng-repeat="notification in notifications" class="notification-item feed-GEPS notification-item_unread">
    <div class="grid-wrap__row">
        <a data-ng-click="openDetails(notification)" class="grid-wrap__col-lg-1 grid-wrap__col-md-1 grid-wrap__col-sm-1 grid-wrap__col-md-land-1 pad-top-24 pad-bottom-24">
            <div class="visually-hidden">Author</div>
            <div class="status-inbox"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="grid-wrap__col-lg-12 grid-wrap__col-md-9 grid-wrap__col-sm-5 grid-wrap__col-md-land-13 pad-top-x-sm pad-bottom-x-sm sm-pad-bottom-none">

            <div>
                <div class="grid-wrap__row">
                    <a data-ng-click="openDetails(notification)" class="grid-wrap__col-lg-24 grid-wrap__col-sm-6 grid-wrap__col-md-12">
                        <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType!== 'FEEDBACK' --><div data-ng-if="notification.feedType!== 'FEEDBACK'" class="offset-top-min">
                            <!-- ngIf: notification.hasLegal ||  notification.isLegal || notification.data.hasRegLetter --><span data-ng-if="notification.hasLegal ||  notification.isLegal || notification.data.hasRegLetter" class="red-flag"></span><!-- end ngIf: notification.hasLegal ||  notification.isLegal || notification.data.hasRegLetter -->
                            <span data-ng-class="{'plain-text-bold': (notification.unread &amp;&amp; notification.feedType != 'DRAFT') || (notification.feedType === 'GEPS' &amp;&amp; notification.data &amp;&amp; notification.data.unreadThread &amp;&amp; notification.data.unreadThread > 1), 'plain-text': !notification.unread || notification.feedType == 'DRAFT'}" class="plain-text-bold">
                                <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType !== 'CLAIM' && notification.feedType !== 'RETURN' --><span data-ng-if="notification.feedType !== 'CLAIM' &amp;&amp; notification.feedType !== 'RETURN'" data-ng-bind-html="(notification.status === 'outbox' &amp;&amp; notification.data.deptMessageType &amp;&amp; notification.data.deptMessageType === 'ORDER' ? notification.data.toName || notification.title : notification.title) | highlight:filter.query">Author</span><!-- end ngIf: notification.feedType !== 'CLAIM' && notification.feedType !== 'RETURN' -->
                                <span data-ng-bind-html="notification.subTitle | highlight:filter.query">Theme</span>
                                <span class="notification-item__unread-thread">&nbsp;(1)</span>
                            </span>
                            <!-- ngIf: ($root.userType === 'B' || $root.userType === 'L') && ((notification.data.orderCreator && notification.data.orderCreator.formattedLoginName) || (fullView && notification.data.orderDescription)) -->
                            <!-- ngIf: !fullView && !notification.data.imOrgName -->
                            <!-- ngIf: showRemoveDraftSign(notification) && $root.isLk -->
                        </div><!-- end ngIf: notification.feedType!== 'FEEDBACK' -->

                        <!-- ngRepeat: snippet in notification.data.snippets -->
                        <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType === 'FEEDBACK' -->
                    </a>
                    <!-- ngRepeat: textSnippet in notification.data.snippets -->

                    <!-- ngIf: notification.data.imOrgName && !fullView -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a data-ng-click="openDetails(notification)" class="grid-wrap__col-lg-4 grid-wrap__col-md-2 grid-wrap__col-sm-6 grid-wrap__col-offset-sm-1 pad-top-x-sm sm-pad-top-extra-sm pad-bottom-x-sm align-right sm-align-left offset-top-min">
            <div class="grid-wrap__row notification-item__controls">
                <div class="grid-wrap__col-lg-4 grid-wrap__col-md-12 grid-wrap__col-sm-6">
                    <div data-ng-show="!notification.deleteError &amp;&amp; isUnread(notification)" class="notification-item__new">updated</div><div data-ng-show="iconsObj.setFixedIcon(notification)" class="notification-item__fixed offset-left-extra-sm ng-hide"></div><!-- ngIf: showNotificationDate(notification) --><div data-ng-class="{'small-light-text': !isUnread(notification), 'notification-item__date': isUnread(notification)}" data-ng-if="showNotificationDate(notification)" class="nowrap small-light-text inline-block offset-left-extra-sm notification-item__event-date notification-item__date"><!-- ngIf: notification.data.snippets[0].type === 'IM' --><!-- ngIf: notification.data.snippets[0].type !== 'IM' --><span data-ng-if="notification.data.snippets[0].type !== 'IM'">Вчера 19:19</span><!-- end ngIf: notification.data.snippets[0].type !== 'IM' --></div><!-- end ngIf: showNotificationDate(notification) -->
                </div>
                <div class="grid-wrap__col-lg-4 grid-wrap__col-md-12 grid-wrap__col-sm-6">
                    <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType == 'DRAFT' && !notification.deleteError && !notification.data.reminder -->
                    <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType == 'GEPS' && notification.status == 'draft' -->
                    <!-- ngIf: notification.hasQuiz -->
                    <!-- ngIf: notification.feedType == 'ORDER' && notification.data &&  notification.data.gisDoSsExtId && notification.data.gisDoLink && !notification.hasQuiz -->
                    <!-- ngIf: !notification.deleteError && notification.feedType == 'PAYMENT' && notification.data.amount -->
                    <div data-ng-show="notification.deleteError" class="notification-item__error ng-hide">
                        do not deleted
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: create an array to store your data... gather webelements, iterate and store the values you need, then click "show more",  repeat (checking the array to see if it already contains the content you are storing)  Hashmaps/Dictionaries can be useful there... I think C# you'd be using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do in this case, its store the loaded elements into

```
var yourList = d.FindElements(whatever you like)
```

the "s" at end of FindElements is important to make the list. After you can use this list to interact with the elements.